# Whether and how to distinguish two kinds of $O(1)$ speedup

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o-notation

Here is a very bad algorithm that computes $4n$ for an integer input.

```
# Original algorithm
function fourtimes(n)
    two = 1 + 1
    res = 0
    
    for i in 1:n
        res += two
        res += two
    end

    return res
end
```

Here is one way of improving the algorithm (**speedup A**).

```
# Speedup A
function fourtimes(n)
    two = 2
    res = 0
    
    for i in 1:n
        res += two
        res += two
    end

    return res
end
```

Here is another way of improving the algorithm (**speedup B**).

```
# Speedup B
function fourtimes(n)
    four = 2 + 2
    res = 0
    
    for i in 1:n
        res += four
    end

    return res
end
```

The original algorithm is $O(n)$, and both **speedup A** and **speedup B** leave this overall complexity the same. Thus, I am inclined to call both of these $O(1)$-speedups.

On the other hand, for large $n$, **speedup A** is barely noticeable, whereas **speedup B** cuts the computation time in half. If the original algorithm takes $1n$ units of time to compute, then **speedup A** takes $1n - \epsilon$ units, whereas **speedup B** takes $\frac{1}{2}n$ units.

I am wondering if there is a way to express mathematically that **speedup B** is a more significant improvement than **speedup A** over the original algorithm—or is it?

If so, can the difference be expressed in big-O notation?

Would it be appropriate to abuse notation and call A an $O(0)$-speedup instead?

Comment: $O(0)$ contains  only functions, which are constantly $0$ after some finite steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can analyze the number of arithmetic operations as a function of $n$. Let us call the algorithms O (for "original"), A (for "speedup A") and B (for "speedup B").

Let us denote by $f_X(n)$ the number of additions performed by algorithm X. We have that

- $f_O(n) = 1 + 3n$,
- $f_A(n) = 0 + 3n$, and
- $f_B(n) = 1 + 2n$.

So the only improvement of A over O is that it avoids computing 1 + 1 by initializing `two` to 2 directly. On the other hand, B is even better as it does one operation less for each round of the loop.

This is a mathematically sound way of expressing that B gives us a more significant saving than A, which is what you wanted. So in particular, there is no need to express any of the $f_X$ in terms of Big Oh. It's good to be as precise as possible whenever you can and it makes sense.